# Can't see localhost from UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, localhost, uwp

I’m working on UWP app on my laptop.  On a previous laptop with a pre-release Windows 10, I was able to get my app to see my web API service on localhost, but on this laptop, no matter what I try, I always get this error using HTTP client:

> A connection with the server could not be established

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(BuildGetRequest()).AsTask(source.Token);
```

If I point to my published service on Azure, everything works fine.
Here’s what I have tried:

- Allowed local network loopback is set in the App’s project properties.
  Confirmed that my app package name is checked in the AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility in Fiddler.
- Set Internet (Client), Internet (Client & Server), Private Networks capabilities in Package.AppManifest
- Tried manually setting c:>checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n= from the command line
- [UWP Enable local network loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback)
- Completely disabled the firewall in an act of pure desperation.
- Run my Web API in full IIS rather than IIS Express.

Nothing makes any difference.

I have noticed that I’m having a similar problem in Edge, despite allowing Localhost loopback in `about:flags` and several other suggestions I found at:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0face535-3c7a-4658-be34-6c376322ca34/microsoft-edge-cant-open-local-domains

My Web API project runs fine in every browser except Edge, so I’m guessing as Edge is a universal app, the problem is linked. When I debug it in Edge, I get this error:

> Can’t connect to the proxy server

If I go to `Settings` and switch off the manual proxy server, run it again I get:

> Hmm, we can’t reach this page

I notice though that for some reason the Manual Proxy server setting keeps switching back on during subsequent runs.

Could anyone suggest anything else I could try to get my UWP app to see my service on localhost?

Comment: I'm hitting the exact same problem, even including the Edge browser not working.

Comment: Got solution for it? Me too facing same issue

Answer (score 34):

It's not a bug it's a feature, called network isolation. It was introduced in Windows 8 (where Metro apps were called Windows Runtime apps).

> For security reasons, a UWP app that is installed in the standard
>   manner is not allowed to make network calls to the device it is
>   installed on.

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640582.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#debugging-options).

The feature can be disabled in Visual Studio debug settings, also the article [*How to allow loopback for Windows Runtime apps*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) talks about using the CheckNetIsolation Windows tool to enable loopback access per application:

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a –p=S-1-15-2-4125766819-3228448775-2449327860-2490758337-1264241865-3581724871-2122349299
```

There are also GUI tools such as **[Enable Loopback Utility](https://telerik-fiddler.s3.amazonaws.com/fiddler/addons/enableloopbackutility.exe)** and [Loopback Exemption Manager](https://github.com/tiagonmas/Windows-Loopback-Exemption-Manager) which make this task easier:

[image: Enable Loopback Utility]

Comment: Problem is that even with all those you can't have a listening Socket or StreamSocket in a UWP app accepting connections from the same machine

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis arrr crap that sucks.  Just found a doc here confirming this "Further, a Windows Runtime app can use an IP loopback only as the target address for a client network request."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh780593.aspx

Comment: funny thing is that if you use the Desktop Bridge to put a Win32 app on the windows store, it will be able to do whatever it wishes regarding networking if I'm not mistaken

Comment: There is now an option for [UWP to communicate with other apps on `localhost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap4-loopbackaccessrules). You still need to [remove network isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj835817(v=win.10) if you want to talk to a non-packaged app.

Comment: The original link to the Enable Loopback Utility doesn't work, so here's a new one: https://telerik-fiddler.s3.amazonaws.com/fiddler/addons/enableloopbackutility.exe

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT  so if you did all the above, how do you use the "uap4:LoopbackAccessRules" link you shared in your comment to allow your local server to accept your local client, say on port 21, host 127.0.0.1  ?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT   according to this Stack post, it is impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525530/loopback-isolation-removal-not-working-for-uwp-app

Answer (score 2):

It might be in the future with the project reunion .

https://github.com/microsoft/ProjectReunion/issues/113

Give your demand some emphasis in this ticket.