# Xamarin UWP HttpRequestException when using non-localhost (PCL)

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm building an application with Xamarin.Forms and a Portable Class Library. 
I try to do an API call which returns JSON. I have problems when running the project on Universal Windows Platform.
This is the code that throws an error:

```
using (HttpClient wc = new HttpClient())
{
   var data = await wc.GetStringAsync("http://something.e1923.companyname.local/content-api/Category/?format=json");
```

This is the error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Somethoing.RESTConnection.d__4.MoveNext()

When I used the same code but an other URL it worked perfect:

```
wc.GetStringAsync("http://something.localhost.companyname.local/content-api/Category/?format=json");
```

The code does work on Android, but not in Universal Windows Platform. 
**Why is the above code (without localhost) not working on UWP?**

I only changed from localhost to an other URL. The only requirement to have access to the non-localhost URL (in my particular case) is that you are connected to the right network (same as where the website is hosted).

Comment: Did you check this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39317424/361100 Anyway, blocking Non-loopback is weird. Blocking loopback is understandable.

Comment: Did you add the required capabilities to your UWP app? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)

Comment: @Krumelur, yes, I have checked the capabalities: Internet (Client) and Internet (Client & Server)

Comment: @Youngjae I read the post and its links, but I still cannot fix the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Krumeler** asked me in the comments if I did add the required capabilities in my UWP app, so I wen't looking.

The one I didn't check was: **Private Networks (Client & Server).**

This was the one that needed to be checked. It works now, thanks!