# Topaz Signature Pad throws Exception: NetworkError when I launch it from JS code inside WebView in Xamarin UWP Windows App

Tags: xamarin, webview, topaz-signatures

Topaz Signature Pad throws Exception: NetworkError when I launch it from JS code inside WebView in Xamarin UWP Windows App.

I do not have problem with Topaz if I run it in regular Web Browser, but from WebView in Xamarin App it throws Exception on this method call:

```
var tmr;

function onSign()
{
   var ctx = document.getElementById('cnv').getContext('2d');         
   SetDisplayXSize( 500 );
   SetDisplayYSize( 100 );
   SetTabletState(0, tmr);
   SetJustifyMode(0);
   ClearTablet();
   if(tmr == null)
   {
      tmr = SetTabletState(1, ctx, 50);
   }
   else
   {
      SetTabletState(0, tmr);
      tmr = null;
      tmr = SetTabletState(1, ctx, 50);
   }
}
```

I am using this Demo:
http://www.sigplusweb.com/sigwebtablet_demo.htm

My Topaz is: T-LBK462-HSB-R
I am using SigWeb SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. You have been most helpful!

Found a solution after tons of research:
It is UWP app **network isolation** : [Can't see localhost from UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589522/cant-see-localhost-from-uwp-app)

Comment: Did you get a topaz signature pad to work in a xamarin uwp app? Did you use the web library to circumvent the fact they only support .NET framework?