# how do Microsoft expect me to debug my server-client applications under UWP?

Tags: uwp, client-server

That's it, straight and simple. I have a TCP server that connect to some devices and grabs data, the whole thing coded in UWP. If client and server are in different machines it works. But in the same machine it wont. I tried forcing different ifaces (WiFi and Ethernet), i tried with a python client. Nothing.

I google, and here in SO there are lots of questions that lead to the same answer: UWP will cut your localhost connections so there is no way for you to reach the server.

Then the question is easy: How should I debug and test my UWP sever - client app ?

Comment: Those answers are no longer relevant. You can see this question / answer and my comment on the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589522/cant-see-localhost-from-uwp-app