# UWP App cannot resolve local domain from hosts file

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have a modified hosts file which is as follows:

```
192.168.10.10 library.test
```

and I try to connect to this domain from a UWP app using HttpClient like so

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var result = await client.GetAsync("http://library.test");
Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
```

but this fails with the following exception

```
  HResult=0x80072EFD
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WordsmithsApp.ViewModels.LoginViewModel.<TryLogin>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\dubif\mods-n-stuff\Coding\Projects\WordsmithsApp\WordsmithsApp\WordsmithsApp\ViewModels\LoginViewModel.cs:line 37




Inner Exception 1:
COMException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

A connection with the server could not be established
```

This same code works fine when using a host such as https://google.com

Comment: Is 192.168.10.10 a different machine, or is it the same machine you are running your app on?  If it's the same machine, you might want to check out this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589522/cant-see-localhost-from-uwp-app

Answer (score 0):

I did not reproduce your problem, when I try to modify the website `library.test` in the host and direct it to the local webpage, it can be accessed normally.

Please check the following:

1. Is `192.168.10.10` an accessible IP address? If you only access the local, you can change to `127.0.0.1`.
2. If you do not set a port number, then the default is access to port 80, please ensure that there is accessible content under this port.

Comment: Tested with Postman and the hosts file modification and works as intended but for some reason the UWP app won't work. I have enabled the private networks capability too just in case

Comment: UWP has restrictions on local network loopback. If your IP address is pointing to a local host, it will be denied access. However, in the debug state, Visual Studio will lift the network loopback restriction by default. You can check your [project settings](https://imgur.com/VEWbu2O) to see if the local network loopback is turned on. If you want to cancel the network loopback in the released state, you can view this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/dn640582(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Network loopback is enebled. I wonder if it's to do with the fact that the hosts modification is pointing to an address in a virtual network adapter. For reference I'm trying to connect to a virtual machine running locally on my machine. It works fine outside of UWP (such as using Postman) but not inside UWP

Comment: This is a strange phenomenon. First of all, we need to confirm that the IP address you provided is a local address or a network address? If I remove the redirection in the hosts file, can you directly access the IP address?

Comment: Yes I can still access the IP directly. I'm not sure on the internals but this specific IP seems to be a way to access the localhost of the virtual machine potentially?

Comment: Since this problem cannot be reproduced (I can redirect to `library.test` on my device), I suggest you can consider directly accessing the IP address in UWP

Comment: I have noticed that `Dns.GetHostAddresses("library.test")[0]` does actually resolve the correct IP which is odd. Maybe this is a bug with HttpClient itself?

Comment: I have now realised that HttpClient also fails with the IP directly too

Comment: I'm not sure if this problem is caused by `HttpClient`, you can try to create a connection to `library.test` using `HttpWebRequest`. If this does not work, then this may be a gateway or proxy issue.

Comment: Same error as HttpClient. `System.Net.WebException
An error occurred while sending the request. `

Comment: Then this should not be a problem with HttpClient, nor is it a redirection set by UWP cannot access the hosts file. This IP may be an address that UWP cannot access in the sandbox

Comment: Taht makes sense. Do you know of any methods around this? I only need to access this IP for development and the release product will connect to an actual remote server.

Comment: I'm not sure why this IP is not accessible, but you can try some other IPs. If you are accessing a local address (such as `localhost`), UWP is accessible in debug state.