# How do I enable loopback for a UWP Windows 10 app as TCP server?

Tags: windows, sockets, universal, loopback

I’m working on Windows 10 with a Universal Windows (UWP) app. 
I’m using a StreamSocketListener in the UWP app to listen as a server. 
I enabled “Internet (Client)” and “Private Networks (Client & Server) in the app manifest. 
I used CheckNetIsolation.exe tool to enable loopback for my UWP app.
This works: sending TCP messages to the UWP app from remote machines.
This fails, but I NEED IT TO WORK: sending TCP messages to the StreamSocketListener in the UWP app from the local machine.
The CheckNetIsolation.exe tool seems to have no effect for UWP app as a server. I need to have the UWP app as a server in order to send messages to the app from a local service. 
Some bad choices I could make as workaround:
I could have the app poll the service, but that's very poor and expensive architecture choice.
I could message the app from a remote machine, but that complicates things and (for complicated reasons) is very undesirable solution.

Can I fix the UWP as TCP server with a registry edit?

Answer (score 2):

```
c:\>checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=package family name
```

[UWP Enable local network loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback)