# net_http_client_execution_error in background task

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I have a project which supports background task.

At client's end, when application tries to make web service connection, net_http_client_execution_error is observed.

> Stack contains some Base address codes.

I can't figure out what could be the possible reason.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Note:** I am unable to reproduce this error on my system (either in debugging or release mode)

Comment: unless we see something we  can't help - this is some related issue as you expressed here hope this will help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback]

Comment: I get net_http_client_execution_error when I put the device in airplane mode, simulating a lost connection, and then suspend the app.

Answer (score 0):

During registration of your background task you will need to set the IsNetworkRequested property (or use the InternetAvailable condition):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder#Windows_ApplicationModel_Background_BackgroundTaskBuilder_IsNetworkRequested

Otherwise you will not be able to access the network from your background task when the device goes into connected standby.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform