# C# server client fails on connect UWP

Tags: c#, client-server, uwp

I try to communicate using a simple TCP client server on UWP, I followed this link [UWP socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) but it looks like it doesn't works. I've added capabilities for both app to provide client & server. Even if it doesn't appear in the code, I have handled the error, which give me the following : `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007274C): A connection attemps has failed because the connected part has not answer after a certain amount of time or the connection has failed because host has not respond`

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007274C): Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu.`

As far I can look, it fails at the line `await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);`

At term, it should run the server on a Rasperry Pi 3 and the Client on a Windows 10 mobile (Lumia 950 XL build 14385) but until now I only terted on a surface pro 3 running Windows 10 Pro (build 14385)

Client

```
try
{
        StreamSocket clientSocket;

        clientSocket = new StreamSocket();
        HostName serverHost = new HostName("localhost");
        string serverPort = "5464";
        await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);
        Stream streamOut = clientSoket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);
        string request = "test";
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        Stream streamIn = clientSocket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
        string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());//handle
    }
```

Server

```
try
{
    serverSocket = new StreamSocketListener();
    serverSocket.ConnectionReceived += ServerSocket_ConnectionReceived;
    await serverSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("5464");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());//handle
}

private async void ServerSocket_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Stream inputStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputStream);
    string request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        Stream outputStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
    StreamWriter writter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
    await writter.WriteLineAsync("Ok");
    await writter.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: What UWP device family are you testing the code on? Desktop, Phone, Pi etc. I ran into the same problem when testing restup. The code worked  on the Pi but I could not get it to work on my desktop machine.

Comment: Later, the server will be on a Pi3 but I tried running on a Windows 10 build 14385

Comment: I am sure you tried this already... but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After some research and thanks to Stuart Smith, It appears that two apps cannot directly connect between each other. For developement purposes, it could be allowed on a local machine, using a tool to enable network loopback. When I tried to run the client on my lumia and the server on my PC, it worked perfectly.

Here are the link used to understand this.

[StackOverFlow UWP Enable loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback)

[Using network loopback in side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640582.aspx)