# C++ UWP and desktop network connection

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, network-programming

I developing two applications that needs to share some information to each other. One application is a UWP and I think I will use streamsocketlistener and streamsocket to send and receive information in UWP side. What shall I do in the desktop side? I am totally confused about the Winsock

Comment: Note that UWP apps are not allowed to do local 'loopback' as you described. There is a way to lift this restriction locally (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback)) but it's for debugging/testing purposes only or in an enterprise scenario, but not for a consumer app.

Comment: I understand that I need to have the UWP running on another device. My question what shall I use on the server side to use the communication standard compatible with websocket that will use RFC6455?