# In UWP TcpListener AcceptTcpClientAsync doesn't work

Tags: c#, uwp, network-programming

I'm porting some TcpListener/TcpClient/etc code to work on UWP. However, the most basic operations which work in a generic windows c# app are failing for me under UWP.

The most basic operation, such as waiting for a TcpClient is failing:

```
private async Task TestTcpListening()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Creating TcpListneer");
    int portNumber = 8554;
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portNumber);
    listener.Start();

    while(true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Waiting on TcpListener to accept client");
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("We got a client! {0}", client));
    }
}
```

If I run this code in a generic windows console application, the "We got a client" bit runs when I tickle the localhost URL. If this runs in a UWP application, it waits forever and the calling app times out.

NOTES:

- I've selected the **Internet (Client & Server)**, **Internet**, and **Private Networks** capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest
- I'm porting an RTSP server, that works fine as a general windows app. As such, the URI I'm using is "rtsp://localhost:8554". When built as a command-line windows app the above code works as expected, when pointing VLC to that URI. The UWP version of the same code waits forever, and VLC times out.
- I'm completely new to Windows, so I don't yet know what I don't know.

THOUGHTS:

- Do I need to enable "rtsp:" protocol access to the app somehow? I don't want the app to open when an rtsp: url is hit. I just want incoming connections to be handled.

Comment: Hi TomorrowPlusX, I guess it has to do with the fact that UWP don't let you work with TcpListeners (Server&Client) on the same device... for developing purposes you can remove that restriction. Check the web for it... I can't send you details... sorry

Comment: Details about loopback has been wrote on [Using network loopback in side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/dn640582(v=win.10)). If this is actually the problem then you can refer to Rob's post on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback)

Comment: Thanks so much - both of you are correct, and this answers my issue. For now, I'm just using VLC on another machine on the network for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to Windows development, and in particular to UWP, I didn't know about the loopback restriction. For the time being, for testing my RTSP port, using VLC on another computer on the same network resolves my issue above.

Comment: This post explains how to resolve this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33263253/7182460