# UWP app doesn't connect to WCF service when service in the same machine

Tags: wcf, uwp

I have a WCF service, up, running an tested, and an UWP app installed in two machines, app installation was made from the store.

Machine 1 has installed WCF service (IIS)  and the app.

Machine 2 Has installed the only the app.

Both machines has the same w10 version 1803

Machine 2 Can run the app and access the service with no problems, but machine one app can't access the service.

The only thing i get from the app is:

**Could not find the text associated with this error code.
A connection to the server could not be established.**

This is totally baffling for me.

This is a test environment. and really any idea could help.

Things I've tried

1. Allow developer mode -> result nothing :(
2. Change service address from name to fixed ip > result nothing :(
3. **EDIT 1:** Manually added this to my app Manifest

   `<Applications>
   <Application . . . >
     <Extensions>
       <uap4:Extension Category="windows.loopbackAccessRules">
         <uap4:LoopbackAccessRules>
           <uap4:Rule Direction="out" PackageFamilyName="MyPFN" />
           <uap4:Rule Direction="in" PackageFamilyName="MyPFN" />
         </uap4:LoopbackAccessRules>
       </uap4:Extension>
     </Extensions>
   </Application>
   </Applications>`

Result=> Nothing :(

Comment: Look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopbackAppContainerDeriveSidFromMoniker) or [this MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap4-loopbackaccessrules)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I'm going to take a look to it. But it means every customer with the same environment configuration must do the same ?

Comment: No you make the change in your app manifest. Your customers don't have to make the change.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Tks peter, what are you talking about MANIFEST ? I have internet access, local network access, but what else must check at manifest ?

Comment: The two links above should tell you what to do.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Finally  running at machine's 1 cmd this command **checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=`<My PFN>`** do the job. But It is a bit cumbersome to run this on every customer **server**.