# Server and client in different projects on the same computer in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server, uwp, client

Hello I was trying to make two programs(server and client) on one machine. I did it with WPF and then I tried to do it with UWP, but I didn't succeed.
The problem is that the listener in the server is waiting for a connection, but it never comes. This only happenes when I try to do the connection from two separate projets.

If I do it in one project everything works fine. I saw somewhere that it is not possible to run the server and client form one machine with UWP, but the information was not so good explained.

So my question is, is it possible to make two separate projects with UWP for server and client on one computer and if not how can I test the programs(Do I need another computer to test it or there is some other way to do it).

Comment: I don't know if it is important to say but I used `StreamSocket` for the client and `StreamSocketListener` of the server.

Comment: Try to [exempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33263253/815938) you client app from the network isolation that prevents it from accessing resource on localhost.