# TCP Client issue in Universal Windows Platform application

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, tcpclient

We are developing UWP application which internally communicating with another application (server application) using specified TCP port number. Below are details.

Server application: It provides some functionalities, opens the TCP port and listens to incoming requests on opened port. It is developed in C#.

UWP Client Application: This application needs to consume the functionalities provided in the server application. For that it creates the socket request with server name and TCP port number and sends the request to the server.

UWP application is able to create a socket request and send it to the server successfully and server application also able to receive the socket, process the request and send the results back as a response to the UWP application.

As this is intranet application, we can maintain the server application in the same machine where UWP client application machine is installed or in other machines connected in same domain.

Result:

It is working fine in the development machine but it is not not working in the end users' machine. So I installed the same UWP published application in other machine to reproduce the same issue.

To resolve this issue, I started debugging the application in newly configured machine. After this same application started working in newly configured machine(I didn't do any fix just debugged that's it). Published application started working in newly configured machine but not working in any other machine. No clue what is happening once we debug

Any thoughts on this....

Thanks in advance.

Srini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP Enable local network loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback)

Answer (score 1):

This happened because of loopback is not enabled for the app. We can enable loopback for the apps by below command

checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=