# uwp httplistener not listening

Tags: uwp, httplistener

I have a ToggleSwitch that launches a `HttpListener` when it is turned on. Below is the code that turns the listener on.

My problem is that the `HttpListener` is not listening. I requested `http://localhost:8023` via Postman and the request is always timed out. And the `GetContextCallBack` is only called when `httpListener.Stop()` is invoked. What's the problem of my code? It works in a console app but does not work in UWP.

```
private void LaunchLocalServer(int port)
{
    httpListener = new HttpListener();
    httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://127.0.0.1:{port}/");
    httpListener.Start();
    httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(GetContextCallBack), httpListener);
}

private void GetContextCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        HttpListener _listener = ar.AsyncState as HttpListener;
        if (_listener.IsListening)
        {
            return;
        }

        HttpListenerContext context = _listener.EndGetContext(ar);
        _listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(GetContextCallBack), _listener);

        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        var abcOject = new
        {
            code = "200",
            description = "success",
            data = "time=" + DateTime.Now
        };
        string responseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abcOject,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
            });

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(responseString);
            writer.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Warn($"handle response failed {ex}");
    }
}
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/RemotePlayPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: Is Windows Firewall blocking it? What do you see in `tcpview`?

Comment: Also, why are you using the _old_ `BeginGetContext` method instead of the _newer and better_ `GetContextAsync` method?

Comment: I don't think Windows Firewall is blocking it. This piece of code works in a console app but does not work in UWP.

Comment: @Dai I googled `HttpListener` and the code demo I got all about `BeginGetContext`, so I used it. I just tried `GetContextAsync`, it was still the same result. The listener only execute the code after `GetContextAsync` when the listener is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

A general reason for this behavior is that you will need to enable the local loopback for the UWP app first- [UWP Enable local network loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259763/uwp-enable-local-network-loopback). UWP apps are running in the sandbox and are isolated from the system resources. Enabling the local network loopback could make UWP apps possible to access local network resources.

Comment: Hi, I have tried `checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=<SMPlayer_gn05p9xsngvjy>` and `checknetisolation loopbackexempt -c`. Both operations were executed but did nothing. I have also referred to the [link][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication] and added capability of `privateNetworkClientServer` to my app, and I still couldn't connect to the local server port. Could you please check my code and see what I am missing?

Comment: @SeakyLone Please make sure that you are using the correct package family name not the package name.